# Spiritism vs Spiritualism

Tags: meaning

From dictionary.com:

> Spiritism - the doctrine or practices of spiritualism
>
> Spiritualism - the belief or doctrine that the spirits of the dead, surviving after the mortal life, can and do communicate with the living, especially through a person (a medium) particularly susceptible to their influence

Is there any *precise* difference between the two, ie, if they are switched in a sentence, would it make much difference?

On that topic, is there any difference between Spiritist, and Spiritualist?

Answer (score 3):

Spiritism is a spiritualistic doctrine codified in the 19th century by the French educator Allan Kardec, proposed as the study of "the nature, origin, and destiny of spirits, and their relation with the corporeal world" (from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiritism))

Spiritualism is a belief that spirits of the dead have both the ability and the inclination to communicate with the living. The afterlife, or "spirit world", is seen by Spiritualists, not as a static place, but as one in which spirits continue to evolve.(from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiritualism))

Spiritism can be used in contexts where there is reference to principles and beliefs as defined by Allan Kardec in his doctrine. For other general usages, Spiritualism will be more apt.

Comment: Thanks, but might want to check the links, they don't seem to be working. Also, could you provide any examples how they might be used in?

Comment: The links are fixed. Thank youfor letting me know about them.

Answer (score 1):

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/186883?redirectedFrom=spiritism#eid) lists spiritism and spiritualism as equal with the caveat:

> [Of 'spiritism'] This form has to some extent been preferred by those specially interested in the subject, as being more distinctive than spiritualism.

Comment: Although I like the OED, I would still side with Kardec's differentiation.